# Modification of Kinchin's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I have question regarding Kinchin's Theorem. Part of the Theorems says the following

**[Kinchin's Theorem] **
Let $p,q\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then if $\sum_{z_x=1}^\infty qf(q)$ diverges where $f(q)$  is nonnegative function, for every constant $c>0$ and  almost every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there are infinitely many  values of $q$ such that 
\begin{align}
\min_{p \in \mathbb{N}} |a-\frac{p}{q}| \le c f(q)
\end{align}

My question is the following. If I restrict values of $p$, say $p \le N$. So, the that we have \begin{align}
\min_{p \in \mathbb{N}: p \le N} |a-\frac{p}{q}|
\end{align}

What can we say about this case?

Clearly the values of q should be finite now, right?

Also, can we even have  a bound of the form

\begin{align}
\min_{p \in \mathbb{N}: p } |a-\frac{p}{q}| \le c f(q)
\end{align}

I am sorry if I am being not clear on something I am not a number theorist. 
Thank you very much.